# Long data is cutoff in tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am displaying tooltip on a div element by setting its title attribute value with my pending customers data. The tooltip consists of several lines of data. The problem is that after 17 lines, the data is cutoff. I tried the following:

```
#pending-customers:hover {
        display: block;
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

where #pending-customers is the id of the div element. Unfortunately I am unable to use bootstrap's tooltip, so I am stuck with pure javascript tooltip.

Comment: Can you reproduce issue at stacksnippets? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen) will do fine as well